# How does Ktor launch coroutines?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm an Android developer trying my hand at building a server with Ktor. As Ktor's community is still growing (and I'm a complete beginner when it comes to backends), I couldn't find any info on how ktor *launches* coroutines.
Take this piece of code, for example:

```kotlin
install(Authentication) {
    form("myAuthForm") {
        mySuspendFunction()
        (...)
    }
}
```

Who is launching a coroutine so that I can call a suspend function inside this lambda?

Comment: I'm also a newbie, but as far as I have understood, everything is running inside the context of a coroutine (which makes sense since KTOR has been built from the ground up using Kotlin Coroutines). This does not mean you have to use Coroutines (actually most examples are synchronous and that's a bit confusing for newcomers) . There is an example project that runs asynchronous code using coroutines https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-samples/tree/1.3.0/feature/async.

Answer (score 0):

The library is

Every request it does something like this

`launch { yourSuspendingHandler(request) }`